# Inconsistent functionality when task unchecked

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit

My To Do app has the functionality to display who completed a task based on the logged in user. For some reason, I can make the text appear below the task when completed (checked) but I can't make it disappear when I uncheck it. However, when I uncheck the task, the task text does change text color like its supposed to. It doesn't seem to make sense as to why one works and the other doesn't. CloudKit Dashboard updates for the done bool (changes from true to false or vice versa) but not for the completedBy key.

```
func doneHit(cell:TaskCell) {
        if let ip = tableView.indexPathForCell(cell) {
            let task = tasks[ip.row]
            let query = CKQuery(recordType: "Tasks", predicate: NSPredicate(format: "TRUEPREDICATE", argumentArray: nil))
            publicData.performQuery(query, inZoneWithID: nil) { (results:[CKRecord]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
                if let _ = results {
                    task["done"] = cell.checkBox.isChecked
                    print(cell.checkBox.isChecked)
                        task["completedBy"] = "Completed by: \(self.user)"
                        cell.label.textColor = UIColor.grayColor()
                    }
                    else {
                        task["completedBy"] = ""
                        cell.label.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
                    }

                    self.publicData.saveRecord(task, completionHandler: { (record:CKRecord?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
                        if error != nil {
                            print("Error: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
                            return
                        }
                        else {
                            print("Saved to iCloud")
                        }

                    })


                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                    })

                }
            }
        }
```

[image: Task is checked and displays user]

[image: Task is unchecked, text changes color but user info remains]

Answer (score 0):

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                    })

// Remove this line from the code
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to be it and if I get rid of that, the tableView won't refresh until I pull-to-refresh. Also, when I get rid of that line it doesn't output the user name to the "Completed By:" line or in the backend. It just spits out "Completed By:"